# GraphQL: Use returned value from field as parameter of sub-query

Tags: graphql

I'm not sure if this is possible in GraphQL as I can't find any examples like this in the GraphQL docs. I want to use a returned value as a parameter in a sub-query. For example:

```
{
  personById(id:"12361067"){

    firstName
    lastName
    accountNumber

    accountDetails(accountNumber:[use accountNumber from above]){
      accountType
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no syntax in GraphQL that would support an operation like that. Moreover, this points to a design issue with the schema you are querying -- if an account number is already associated with the person being queries, there should be no need to require that as an argument on `accountDetails`.

Comment: That's useful to know. Thanks @DanielRearden.